# Atributo old() en Jquery

Tags: jquery, blade

En mi plantilla `blade` tengo:

```
{{ Form::select('idnumero', $numero, old('idnumero'), ['id'=>'numero']) }}
```

Quiero utilizar el `old('idnumero')` en jquery, ¿hay alguna forma?

Comment: No , en `Jquery` no . el `old` pertenece a la sintaxis de `blade` de **PHP**  , No tiene nada que con `Jquery` ni `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

Lo asignas a un atributo data, en Blade

```
{{ Form::select('idnumero', $numero, old('idnumero'), 
   ['id'=>'numero', 'data-oldvalue'=> old('idnumero')]) }}
```

Y luego en jQuery lo lees así

```
var numeroOldValue = $('#numero').data('oldvalue');
```

Un ejemplo funcional con html estático (aqui el old value es 1):

```js
$('#numero').on('change', function() {
  var oldValue = $(this).data('oldvalue');
  var selValue = $(this).val();
  console.log("old:", oldValue, "actual:", selValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numero" data-oldvalue="1" name="idnumero">
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
  <option value="3">D</option>
</select>
```